# SQL UPDATE option_value WHERE `option_name` = '%category_%' problem

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm trying to change a value inside the `wp_options` table from `cat_img_alt` to `img_alt`. The problem is that I need to do so ONLY WHERE the option_name is something like: `%category_%`.

Using the SQL below is not doing so. Where's the problem?

```
UPDATE wp_options
    SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'cat_img_alt', 'img_alt') 
    WHERE `option_name` = '%category_%';
```

Comment: try this: UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'cat_img_alt', 'img_alt') WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%category_%';

Comment: can you pls check your sql - do you want to use `LIKE` instead of `=`. change this part ` WHERE option_name like '%category_%';`

Comment: You want `LIKE`, not `=`.